# Can Q Subscription in Q-replication be loaded/exported

Tags: db2

I'm new to Q- rep. I've gone through the IBM doc on the topic.There is a step regarding Q subscription, we have a requirement to replicate 250 plus tables.
What I'm supposed to do is to create a replication q map & then use them for q subscription,
-> specify the queues that will be used to transmit data 
-> the rows and columns that we want to replicate.
This is a bulky task since we've more than 250 tables.

What i couldn't figure out is that, is there a way to export the Q subscription that is prepared once?
What I mean is that once I create Q subscription & perform Q replication at offshore, can my Subscription mapping be exported & send to onsite so that the same procedure can be done only without any need for manually performing Q subscription step again?

Answer (score 0):

The Replication Center, which you presumably are going to use to configure replication, will indeed generate a script that you would run to implement the changes. You can save this script and reuse it in other environments. http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.repl.qrepl.doc/topics/iiyrqrcccrunsqls.html